# SQL - Execution Plan - Why is a Hash Match used for the JOIN operation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash, inner-join, sql-execution-plan

Quick question - why is there a Hash Match used for the following query?

`BusinessentityID` is of type `Int` and at this point I currently can't really explain why they need to use hashing at all?

Wouldn't a merge be faster with a trivial array like data structure?

Although I guess it would make sense in case when a different data type e.g a `GUID` is used in the join clause?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code; you have enough reputation to know that code should be supplied as `text`. As for why, please also include the DDL of your tables **including all** indexes. Thanks.

Comment: You'll get a `MERGE JOIN` if you drop the covering `IX_Person_LastName_FirstName_MiddleName` index from the `Person.Person` table. The optimizer used the covering index and a hash join due because it was less costly.

Comment: TBH it doesn't sound like you understand what a hash or merge join are from your question. you might want to read https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/08/10/hash-join/ and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/08/03/merge-join/

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks a lot! I will have a look at those!

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the fastest type of `join` is going to use indexes.  So, if you care about performance, add indexes on `businessentityid`.

A merge join is used when the data is already sorted.  If it is not sorted, then the sort is rather expensive -- O(n log(n)).

A hash join, by contrast, requires "just" hashing the values and comparing them in bins.  Under many circumstances, this is O(n).  Of course, if your data is really large or if some values repeat many times, then the hash join will have memory issues or hash collisions -- and the complexity of the algorithm increases.

The key point, though, is that the optimizer chooses the algorithm that it considers best suited to the data.  If performance is your primary consideration, then an index is highly recommended.

Comment: One quick caveat that often gets overlooked: indexes are not free, particularly with a large or frequently changing table, so you should look at how much gain you actually get in realistic queries from adding it.

Comment: The reason why I ask is I currently don't undertand why you would need to hash integers? From my very basic understanding of data structures this doesn't add up for me. Nevertheless @MartinSmith pointed out some interesting articles and I hope I will find my answer there.

Comment: @HansMusterWhatElse . . . Because they can extend up to about 2 or 4 billion.  That is a lot of bins.  And, if that is your question, then the question is unclear.

Comment: @HansMusterWhatElse - why hash integers? Because most parts of the database engine don't feature specialised operators dedicated to individual data types. The engine may use the hash join operator even if (I don't know, haven't checked) the implementation of hashing for integers happens to be the identity function.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever This would also make sense and was also something I assumed! Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know the hash function which they are using for this operation?

Comment: @HansMusterWhatElse . . . I don't specifically know.  I would be surprised if it were the identity for integers.  That is possible, but more likely, it would just take an array of bytes and produce an integer, regardless of initial data type.